# How to make a div section responsive in a vertical website

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I am creating a vertical website that has several different sections.
I want to make each section responsive to the content it has, but it seems like it's not responsive right now. Those two texts on the first row below the navbar is supposed to be in two different lines because it is written like:

```
<div id="firstRow">
    <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
        <div class="intro">
            <div>Welcome to my website</div>
            <div>Scroll down to know more about us</div>
        </div>

</div>
```

and I tried to use flex to make the first div responsive

```
div#firstRow {
    padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you update your code on jsFiddle or Codepen showing the entire code?

Comment: We need to see the CSS you use for the `.intro` class

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the `display: flex` property to your `.intro` div and also add a flex-direction of `row` to put it on the same line:

```
.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qg62nfj/).

Answer (score -1):

do it something like this

```
.intro > div {
 float:left;
 clear: both;
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: is > just same as putting .intro inside the div { } in scss?

Comment: @user6792790 No, it is not, it is the opposite.